# Need table scroll instead of body scroll when placed within CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-tables, css-grid

I have a table placed within a div. The table goes beyond the width of the div. And the div has `overflow-x` set to scroll. Below code works alright

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.table-section {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.table-section table {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.table-section table th {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-section">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Col 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 3
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 4
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 5
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 6
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 7
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 8
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
```

However, if I place the whole thing within a grid cell, the `overflow-x` does not seem to work. And the document body has the scroll. Code below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 1fr;
}

.table-section {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.table-section table {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.table-section table th {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="table-section">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Col 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 3
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 4
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 5
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 6
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 7
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 8
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is it not working within a grid-cell? And how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: CodePen is available at https://codepen.io/vijayst/pen/vMOYrJ if you want to try it out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't normally mix *tables* with *grids*. Anyway, note that in Firefox 66 *overflow* works fine, while in Chrome it doesn't. Remove `width: 100%` from `table-section` and it works fine without it in both:

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 1fr;
}

.table-section {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.table-section table {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.table-section table th {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="table-section">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Col 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 3
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 4
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 5
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 6
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 7
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 8
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your table is smaller than the grid cell - to *fix*, you can consider `min-width: 100%` and `box-sizing: border-box` to account for the `padding` in the *width* calculations:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 1fr;
}

.table-section {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  min-width: 100%; /* changed */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
}

.table-section table {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.table-section table th {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="table-section">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Col 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 3
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 4
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 5
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 6
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 7
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 8
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` instead of `width:100%`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 1fr;
}

.table-section {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  min-width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.table-section table {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.table-section table th {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="table-section">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Col 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 3
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 4
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 5
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 6
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 7
          </th>
          <th>
            Col 8
          </th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove some kind of codes and create new one.

> `padding:10px` on the **.table-section** class then wrap the table to another **div**.

**see my fiddle here** https://jsfiddle.net/c0mx9Lzv/4/